# Behaviour of dataprovider when one of the row is failed to process in @test method

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm new to TestNG framework. I'm planning to use DataProvider to pass the list of form values from the excel sheet.

Let's say add product from the list in excel sheet. The `@test` method will run for each row from the excel sheet when I use data provider?

What happens when one of the row failed to process? Does it run the rest of the rows after this failure? Do I have to re-initiate the selenium webdriver and login method again when it fails? I do not want to re initiate the webdriver for each failure..

My current application will retain the session even when the browser closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question** :  The `@test` method will run for each row from the excel sheet when I use data provider?

**Ans** : Yes, it will run for each set of data. It depends on you how you read data from excel file.

Take this as an example :

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };

@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

The **verifyData1** method will be running **two** times irrespective of any set of data, irrespective of whether first one failed or not.

**Q :** What happens when one of the row failed to process?
**Ans :** Test case would be failed for that particular row , and execution will continue by reading the next set of data from excel.

**Q.** Does it run the rest of the rows after this failure?
**Ans :** Ideally it should , now again it depends whether you have `@AfterMethod` with you or not.

**Q.**  Do I have to re-initiate the selenium webdriver and login method again when it fails?

**Ans :** No. It's better if you are initializing driver in `@BeforeMethod` , because before method would be running prior to each set of data which is generated by dataprovider.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Good and detail answer\

Comment: cruisepandey - "now again it depends whether you have AfterMethod with you or not." - Can you please let me know what should be used under @AfterMethod so that all data under dataprovider is executed, irrespective of previous pass/fail?

Comment: Yes, and I got the reason behind the issue. The default behavior of TestNG (to run all data of dataprovider) is overwritten in the framework. That's why on failure the execution stops.